# Safari Extension - images in dynamic extension menu

Tags: safari

I'm working on a Safari Extension with a dynamic Extension Menu.

I am trying to place an icon by each dynamic entry in the menu.

When I reference an image on a server:

```
var menuItem = event.target.appendMenuItem("bb"+i, i+" - "+itemTitle);
menuItem.image = 'http://www.google.com/favicon.ico';
```

the image appears by each menu item, however, when I try to use an image in my extension:

```
var menuItem = event.target.appendMenuItem("bb"+i, i+" - "+itemTitle);
menuItem.image = 'menu.png';
```

the image won't show.

What's going wrong here -  the code is in mu global.html file, and the image is in the same location as the global.html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer so here it is for anyone else with the wanting to know:

```
var menuItem = event.target.appendMenuItem("bb"+i, i+" - "+itemTitle);
menuItem.image = safari.extension.baseURI+'menu.png';
```